# Как заставить блок появиться и исчезнуть через некоторое время?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть скрипт, который при добавлении товара в корзину выводит через fancybox блок с уведомлением, что товар добавлен. Но он его выводит перед тегом body. Поискал информацию, оказалось, что вывести в другом месте, нужно править сам файл скрипта fancybox.

```
$.fancybox({
              'type' : 'inline',
              'content' : $(message),
              tpl: {
                wrap     : '<div class="fancybox-wrap fancybox-desktop fancybox-type-html fancybox-opened"><div class="fancybox-skin"><div class="fancybox-outer"><div class="fancybox-inner"></div></div></div></div>'
              },
              helpers: {
                overlay: null
              },
              afterLoad: function(){
                setTimeout( function() {$.fancybox.close(); },3000);
              }
            });
```

Может можно как-то напрямую через append и remove, но не соображу как при этом ещё и настроить исчезновение через определённое время

Comment: А afterLoad не срабатывает разве?

Comment: А Вы попробуйте задать правила в CSS для классов шаблона fancybox-wrap fancybox-desktop fancybox-type-html fancybox-opened. Или добавьте свой класс и попробуйте его вывести на страницу как нужно Вам.

Comment: Он позиционируется относительно body, а не нужного мне div. И стоит div сдвинуться, как наложение пропадает

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос.

```
$(".1").append('<div class="2">'+message+'</div>'); 
setTimeout(function () {
                $('.2').remove();
            }, 1000)
```